# Copying and resizing pictures, depending on user input

Tags: vba, modules

I'm working on a macro which copies some pictures to a new sheet, then resizes the pictures. The user can input a number 1, 2, ..., 5 and, depending on the number, the macro returns a different set of pictures. I've managed to get a working macro (copied below) but there is a lot of repetition, the macro essentially boils down to a big `If` statement:

`If obj_n = 1 Then [code to get pictures] ElseIf obj_n = 2 Then [code to get pictures] ...`

The `[code to get pictures]` part is very similar in each case, the only difference being

- The names of the pictures
- The colors of the text

Is there a way to store the `[code to get pictures]` in another macro, and then call that macro for each part of the `If` statement?

Here's the full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateResources()
  ' Creates a version of the resources sheet with the relevant tables

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


  Dim pic As Object
  Dim obj_n As Integer

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resources")
    ' Clear any pictures already on the page
    For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
      pic.Select
      pic.Delete
    Next pic

    On Error GoTo Ender
    obj_n = .Range("Y5")

    If obj_n = 1 Then
      ' Get the pictures
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kwa_1].Copy
      .Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[obj_desc1].Copy
      .Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[im_1].Copy
      .Range("S5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kdp_1].Copy
      .Range("N15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kr_1].Copy
      .Range("N29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Set text colours
      .Range("B13").Font.Color = 12611584
      .Range("N13").Font.Color = 12611584
      .Range("N27").Font.Color = 12611584
      .Range("B36").Font.Color = 12611584
    ElseIf obj_n = 2 Then
      ' Get the pictures
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kwa_2].Copy
      .Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[obj_desc2].Copy
      .Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[im_2].Copy
      .Range("S5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kdp_2].Copy
      .Range("N15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kr_2].Copy
      .Range("N29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Set the text colours
      .Range("B13").Font.Color = 4626167
      .Range("N13").Font.Color = 4626167
      .Range("N27").Font.Color = 4626167
      .Range("B36").Font.Color = 4626167
    ElseIf obj_n = 3 Then
      ' Get the pictures
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kwa_3].Copy
      .Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[obj_desc3].Copy
      .Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[im_3].Copy
      .Range("S5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kdp_3].Copy
      .Range("N15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kr_3].Copy
      .Range("N29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Set the text colours
      .Range("B13").Font.Color = 192
      .Range("N13").Font.Color = 192
      .Range("N27").Font.Color = 192
      .Range("B36").Font.Color = 192
    ElseIf obj_n = 4 Then
      ' Get the pictures
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kwa_4].Copy
      .Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[obj_desc4].Copy
      .Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[im_4].Copy
      .Range("S5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kdp_4].Copy
      .Range("N15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Set the text colours
      .Range("B13").Font.Color = 10498160
      .Range("N13").Font.Color = 10498160
      .Range("N27").Font.Color = 10498160
      .Range("B36").Font.Color = 10498160
    ElseIf obj_n = 5 Then
      ' Get the pictures
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kwa_5].Copy
      .Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[obj_desc5].Copy
      .Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[im_5].Copy
      .Range("S5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kdp_5].Copy
      .Range("N15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Objectives").[kr_5].Copy
      .Range("N29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ' Set the colours
      .Range("B13").Font.Color = 5287936
      .Range("N13").Font.Color = 5287936
      .Range("N27").Font.Color = 5287936
      .Range("B36").Font.Color = 5287936
    Else
      GoTo Ender
    End If

    ' Resize the pictures
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures(1)
      .Height = 312
      .Width = 511
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures(2)
      .Height = 112
      .Width = 759
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures(3)
      .Height = 87
      .Width = 106
    End With
    .Range("Y5").Select
  End With
Ender:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The first idea would be to wrap the repeated code in a function (or rather sub as you dont need a return value), with source/destination ranges as parameters

Comment: A lookup table (array) for kwa_1 etc. would also remove the need for the if's

Answer (score 1):

Main changes I made when refactoring:

- Moved all hard-codded values to the top (constants) where they can be updated easier

  - all constants are strings holding separate values for each set
  - these string are split and used as arrays in For loops
  - naming convention for images is not very descriptive but it's consistent (setID at end)
- Replaced the For loop used to delete all images with `Worksheet.Pictures.Delete`
- Added the Sleep API to force the paste operation to wait - this was causing the errors

  - on my machine waiting 0.7 seconds was long enough, but I made it 0.9 seconds
- All ranges are updated at once (using `Join()`)

---

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long)
#End If

Public Sub PopulateResources()
    Const DELIM = " "
    Const DELIM_RNG = ","
    Const PIC_SET   As String = "kwa_ obj_desc im_ kdp_ kr_"
    Const COPY_RNG  As String = "B15 B5 S5 N15 N29"
    Const FONT_RNG  As String = "B13 N13 N27 B36"
    Const SET_CLR   As String = "12611584 4626167 192 10498160 5287936"
    Const SET_SIZE = "312 511 112 759 87 106"   'holds pairs of Height and Width

    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, wsObj As Worksheet, cellID As Range, setID As Long
    Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resources")
    Set wsObj = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List Objectives")
    Set cellID = wsRes.Range("Y5")
    setID = IIf(Not IsError(cellID), IIf(Len(cellID) > 0, Abs(cellID.Value2), 1), 1)

    wsRes.Pictures.Delete           'remove all pix

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim picSet As Variant, cpyRng As Variant, setClr As Variant, fntRng As Variant

    picSet = Split(PIC_SET, DELIM)
    cpyRng = Split(COPY_RNG, DELIM)
    setClr = Split(SET_CLR, DELIM)
    fntRng = Split(FONT_RNG, DELIM)

    Dim i As Long, ub As Long       'all sets are 5 pix (ub), except set4: 4 pix
    ub = UBound(picSet):    If setID = 4 Then ub = ub - 1

    For i = LBound(picSet) To UBound(picSet)
        wsObj.Shapes(picSet(i) & setID).Copy
        Sleep 0.9   'Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        wsRes.Range(cpyRng(i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        If i = 1 Then wsRes.Range(Join(fntRng, DELIM_RNG)).Value2 = setClr(i)
        If i < 5 Then wsRes.Range(Join(fntRng, DELIM_RNG)).Font.Color = setClr(i)
    Next

    Dim setSize As Variant, j As Long
    setSize = Split(SET_SIZE, DELIM)
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To 3
        With wsRes.Pictures(i)
          .Height = setSize(j)
          .Width = setSize(j + 1)
          j = j + 2
        End With
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```